# How to write files dynamically into subdirectory by FileWritingMessageHandler

Tags: file, spring-integration, message-handlers

I have to write files into multiple subdirectories based on a header attribute.
Not getting a way to configure it in Spring Integration.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processingChannel")
public MessageHandler processingDirectory() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("some-path"));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    handler.setTemporaryFileSuffix(".writing");
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
}
```

This bean receives a file along with some headers attributes i.e. type="abc" from "processingChannel" . Files are written successfully into some-path. But my requirement is to write into somepath/abc or somepath/xyz location based on "type" value

Answer (score 1):

Use a SpEL expression

```java
new FileWritingMessageHandler(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
    "headers['someHeaderWithTheDestinationPath']"));
```

Comment: I tried it and got the following exception: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null`.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, it implies the message is `null` which should not be possible; I suggest you ask a new question showing your code and configuration.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I read your comment, the error disappeared... I'll post a new question if ever I figure out what I did wrong the first time. Thanks.

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72816425/5873923